# Laravel globally join the parent table and the children to be accessed in all views

Tags: laravel, authentication, join, global

I have three tables:

1. `users`: has `id`, `name`, `email`, `password`.
2. `profiles` : has `id`, `user_id`, `age`, `sex`.
3. `addresses` : has `id`, `user_id`, `address`, `city`, `zip`.

Is there any ways to join them to be used globally in all views instead of doing it in every controllers??

So, when I need the address in a view, I could access it by simply using `{{Auth::user()->address}}` or something like that

If it is possible, could you please give me an example on how to implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wants to use `Auth` like this then you have to define relations

> User.php

```
public function address(){
 return $this->hasOne('YourAddressModel','user_id');
}

public function profile(){
   return $this->hasOne('YourProfileModel','user_id','id');
 }
```

> 

Comment: should i set `belongsTo(user)` in both children models too?

Comment: @DaddiAlAmoudi yess you should but these are not necessary

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know the answer is as this simple.